# Como fazer a pagina Login se tornar uma rota padrão de uma aplicação Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

A página Login esta dentro das seguinte pastas Area - Identity - Pages - Account.

Como fazer para que a Pagina Login se torne uma rota padrão, isto é quando o usuário acessar a aplicação Asp.Net Core 2.2 vá direto para a página de login.

A rota padrão no momento é esta abaixo.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Eu tentei assim e não funcionou.

routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "**Identity/**{controller=**Account**}/{action=**Login**}/{id?}");

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo para falar a verdade não entendi suas resposta. Em Startup.cs podemos configurar rotas, quero que o login seja a página inicial de minha aplicação, tentei assim e não deu certo :           routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "Identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

Comment: Qual é o motivo da página de login ser a inicial? O usuário vai poder continuar navegando mesmo sem fazer o login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é questão de rota: é questão de tornar todos os controllers protegidos por um filtro de autorização padrão. Uma vez que todos os controllers estarão protegidos, todos os acessos serão redirecionados à página de login. Somente após o login os controllers poderão ser acessados.

Para isso, altere o método `ConfigureServices` em sua classe `Startup`:

De:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

Para:

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Caso queira que algum controle seja exibido por usuários não autenticados, basta usar a anotação `[AllowAnonymous]` como de costume:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index() => View();
```